# Pymongo - Search and leave duplicates fast

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

I have some data in my `MongoDB` - a lot of data.
And I want to add new data with `pymongo`, but dont append data which already exists in DB based on `phone_number`. I'm using this code, but its only a loop in loop, so its slow as hell...

```py
connected_db = self.main_mongo_terema # Connect to DB
data_to_insert = []
try:
    collection = connected_db['terema_data'] # Connect to Collection
except:
    self.log("Cant connect to DB")
try:
    for dicts_ in data: # list of dicts
        for key, val in dicts_.items():
            if key == "phone_number":
                match = collection.find({}, {"phone_number": val })
                for x in match:
                    if x:       
                        continue
                    else:
                        data_to_insert.append(dicts_)
except Exception as e:
    self.log(f"Loop problem - {str(e)}")
try:
    collection.insert_many(data_to_insert)

# Empty list
except TypeError:
    pass
```

Something like this:

```
dict_ = [{'phone_number':0123, 'col1':'abc'}, {'phone_number':'456', 'col1':'def'}]
```

When dic['phone_number']: 'value' from dict_ not in DB add dic to DB, else do nothing

Comment: What about adding an unique index on `phone_number`?

Comment: like this `collection .create_index("phone_number", unique=True)`? How could I add data to the DB after creating the index?  `Insert` ?  `Update`?

Comment: `phone_number` key is present in all the dictionaries of `data`?

Comment: `data` is a list of dictionaries where `phone_number` is a key in every dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using three nested loops, so in simple words time complexity will be `O(n^3)`, which will be like hell, if there is more data.

You can speed up the insert operation with [`bulk_write()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html). [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) operator will be helpful here.

```py
from pymongo import UpdateOne


requests = []

try:
    for dict_ in data:
        requests.append(UpdateOne({'phone_number': dict_['phone_number']},
                                  {
                                      '$setOnInsert': {
                                          'field1': dict_['field1'],
                                          'field2': dict_['field2'],
                                          # Rest of the fields.
                                      }
                                  },
                                  upsert=True))
    db.collection.bulk_write(requests)
except:
    self.log(f"Loop problem - {str(e)}")
```

Comment: btw. this looks like it only updates the existing one in `field1`, `field2` based on `phone_number`, I would like to leave existing `field1`, `field2` without change and add only records where `phone_number` is not in DB yet

Comment: Could you give few examples of `dict_`, your existing collection and how you want the collection to look like after the query? So, that I can try in local machine and check, what can be improved.

Comment: Something like this:
dict_ = `[{'phone_number':0123, 'col1':'abc'}, {'phone_number':'456', 'col1':'def'}]`. | When dic['phone_number']: 'value' from dict_ not in DB add dic to DB, else do nothing

Comment: I have updated my answer. I would suggest you to update the OP also, so that it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Create an unique index so that you do not have to check whether the number exists or not.

Create a index by the following command:

```
collection.createIndex( { "phone_number": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

PS: You only need to do this once. After that all the `phone_number`(s) in the database will always be unique.

After that you can insert the `data` object directly. You do not need to check if the value is unique or not, mongodb will handle that for you.

```
collection.insert_many(data)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I did it - remove all data from DB, created unique index and uploaded data back, but this time I'm getting `pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred` from `insert_many`

Comment: I'm getting above error on first record in my list. Here are the details
`writeConcernErrors': [], 'nInserted': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 0, 'nModified': 0, 'nRemoved': 0, 'upserted': []`